# Subclassing UICollectionViewCell leads to never being selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionviewcell

I've tried subclassing a UICollectionViewCell and loading from a nib file:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        NSArray *arrayOfViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DatasetCell" owner:self options:nil];

        if ([arrayOfViews count] < 1) {
            return nil;
        }

        if (![[arrayOfViews objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[UICollectionViewCell class]]) {
            return nil;
        }

        self = [arrayOfViews objectAtIndex:0];

        UIView *view = [UIView new];
        view.frame = self.frame;
        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
        self.selectedBackgroundView = view;
    }

    return self;
}
```

I'm running into an issue where a cell is selected, the `cell.selected` is not being set. It is always `NO` which is leading to an issue of deselecting the cells.

How do I handle getting the cell to the selected state?

EDIT:

I originally loading the custom UICollectionViewCell as a class:

```
[collectionView registerClass:[DatasetCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"dataCell"];
```

Switched to loading the nib:

```
[collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"DatasetCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"nibCell"];
```

I have the same select/deselect issue both ways.

Comment: You overwrite the value of `self` before assigning `view.frame = self.frame` - that looks suspicious.

Comment: Why is this code necessary at all? If you use `registerNib:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:` and `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:` in your collection view controller, the custom cell is loaded directly from the NIB file.

Comment: my Nib has labels that I need change the values. This is the first time I'm working with a nib (normally do it programiclly). Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I think you can use the 2 methods mentioned above in the view controller. In the table view subclass you can override `awakeFromNib` to make modifications.

Comment: Ok, I changed it from loading the class to loading the nib. The selecting and deselecting is working as intended but I'm unsure how to gain acess to the UILabels in it now. I changed the nib's class from MyCustomUICollectionView to UICollectionViewClass.

Comment: You have to set the cell's class to your collectionviewcell-subclass. Don't set a class on the file's owner. Then you can control-drag connections from the cell in the nib file to the .h file of your subclass.

Comment: Ok, I switched it back to my Custom Class and load it from nib and still have the select/deselect issue.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26750/discussion-between-martin-r-and-log139)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main error is that you have defined a property

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL isSelected;
```

in your custom UICollectionViewCell subclass (in "DatasetCell.h"), which interferes with the inherited "selected" property of UICollectionViewCell.

If you remove that property definition, selection and deselection works as expected, at least for the cells loaded from the nib file via `registerNib:...`.

For the cells loaded via `registerClass:...`, `initWithFrame` is called. You try to load the cell from the nib file there. That does not make much sense and seems not to work correctly. You should either create the cell programmatically in `initWithFrame` and use `registerClass:`, or create the cell in the nib file and use `registerNib:`.

`initWithFrame` is not called for cells loaded from the nib file, use `awakeFromNib` if you want to make modifications to the cell.

Hope that helps!!

Comment: For UICollectionViewCell subclasses, should awakeFromNib be used to initialize IB outlet properties (e.g., position, width) even if no custom XIB is used?