# Manipulate IB Outlets in awakeFromNib for UICollectionViewCell even if not using custom XIB?

Tags: ios, storyboard, uicollectionview, xib, uicollectionviewcell

The code below is used to manipulate and configure IB Outlets of a subclassed UICollectionViewCell.

The IB outlets in the class, however, are not yet connected at this stage.

Other SO posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15578915/subclassing-uicollectionviewcell-leads-to-never-being-selected) suggest using awakeFromNib to manipulate the IB outlets, but in all the answers, the problem deals with a custom XIB.

However, this subclass doesn't use a custom XIB.

Is it still right to use awakeFromNib to configure the IB outlets even if no custom XIB is used?

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    doInit(frame)
}


required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    doInit(frame)
}

private func doInit(frame: CGRect) {
}
```

Comment: If you aren't using a NIB file (or a storyboard), IBOutlets are meaningless.  You can assign UI elements you create programatically, buy you don't need the `@IBOutlet` preprocessor directive.  If your layout depends on knowing the size of the view's frame then you are best to create your elements in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Comment: @Paulw11 the app uses Storyboard but not a custom XIB for this UICollectionViewCell subclass. All the other answers dealt with questions relating to classes with custom XIBs. So is awakeFromNib still appropriate if not using a custom XIB?

Comment: If you are using a storyboard, yes.

Comment: @Paulw11 ok great could you please post as an answer and elaborate why so you can receive credit?